# Process git failed to spawn

Tags: windows, git, hadoop-yarn

Got this error when running yarn, what's wrong?

```
➤ YN0001: │ gulp-sftp@git+https://git@github.com/webksde/gulp-sftp: Process git failed to spawn
➤ YN0001: │   Thrown Error: spawn git ENOENT
```

I already installed git and it is available